# JQuery sort an array by multiple values (Weighting)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multi dimension array like below, I want to do some fancy sorting but I am not sure how to approach it. I want to sort the array elements first by the 5th element, then the 4th, then 3rd, then 2nd, then 1st (not including the 0th element - i.e. the name).

Essentially weighting the sort. I may need to do the opposite sort later on (sort by 1st, then 2nd, then 3rd, then 4th, then 5th).

```
arr[0]["Array Name 1", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
arr[1]["Array Name 2", 0, 0, 0, 5, 2]
arr[2]["Array Name 3", 97, 0, 0, 6, 50]
arr[3]["Array Name 4", 97, 0, 0, 0, 0]
arr[4]["Array Name 5", 96, 0, 0, 0, 12]
arr[5]["Array Name 6", 97, 2, 0, 0, 2]
arr[6]["Array Name 7", 97, 3, 0, 0, 0]
arr[7]["Array Name 8", 96, 0, 0, 4, 1]
arr[8]["Array Name 9", 96, 0, 1, 0, 0]
arr[9]["Array Name 10", 96, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

I hope that makes sense, I saw that I may need to do a comparison i.e.

```
var arr = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
```

but I can't find something that fits my use case.

Comment: The only restriction of the method you give to the sort is that it should return a numerical value, to denote if the element is <, ==, or > than the other.  How you do that is up to you.  In your case, you could return the 5th elements minus each other, unless they are equal, in which case you'd then return the 4th elements minus each other, unless they are equal, in which case ...  See the pattern?

Comment: I guess the idea in my head came across as the whatever the first element to sort by is the most important and thus carries the most weight. Have you got any examples using the provided array you could provide? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a subset of the values and reverse the temporary array. Then iterate with a short circuit for the delta of values.

```js
var array = [["Array Name 1", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ["Array Name 2", 0, 0, 0, 5, 2], ["Array Name 3", 97, 0, 0, 6, 50], ["Array Name 4", 97, 0, 0, 0, 0], ["Array Name 5", 96, 0, 0, 0, 12], ["Array Name 6", 97, 2, 0, 0, 2], ["Array Name 7", 97, 3, 0, 0, 0], ["Array Name 8", 96, 0, 0, 4, 1], ["Array Name 9", 96, 0, 1, 0, 0], ["Array Name 10", 96, 0, 1, 1, 0]];

array.sort((a, b) => {
   var aa = a.slice(1).reverse(),
       bb = b.slice(1).reverse(),
       delta;
       
   aa.some((v, i) => delta = v - bb[i]);
   return delta;
});

console.log(array.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: So much more elegant than mine, although jsPerf suggests recursion is faster, in Chrome at least: https://jsperf.com/sorting-patterns/1

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks, it took me a little bit to understand it as I haven't seen the functions you've used like delta and some before (I assume they are some sort of magic). I get the gist of it though.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note that this isn't weighting. It's simply sorting by multiple conditions.

To achieve what you require I'd suggest creating a function to do the comparison which you pass the index to. Then you can recursively call this function decrementing the index on each call when the values are equal. The function would return a value to the `sort()` handler denoting what to do with the index of the current element. Something like this:

```js
var arr = [["Array Name 1", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ["Array Name 2", 0, 0, 0, 5, 2], ["Array Name 3", 97, 0, 0, 6, 50], ["Array Name 4", 97, 0, 0, 0, 0], ["Array Name 5", 96, 0, 0, 0, 12], ["Array Name 6", 97, 2, 0, 0, 2], ["Array Name 7", 97, 3, 0, 0, 0], ["Array Name 8", 96, 0, 0, 4, 1], ["Array Name 9", 96, 0, 1, 0, 0], ["Array Name 10", 96, 0, 1, 1, 0]];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return doSort(a, b)
});

function doSort(a, b, i) {
  i = i || a.length - 1;
  var diff = a[i] - b[i];
  if (diff == 0)
    diff = doSort(a, b, --i);        
  return diff;  
}

console.log(arr);
```